# Keras Multitask learning with two different input sample size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

I am implementing multitask regression model using code from the Keras [API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) under the shared layers section.

There are two data sets, Let's call them `data_1` and `data_2` as follows.

```
data_1 : shape(1434, 185, 37)
data_2 : shape(283, 185, 37)
```

`data_1` is consists of 1434 samples, each sample is 185 characters long and 37 shows total number of unique characters is 37 or in another words the `vocab_size`. Comparatively `data_2` consists of 283 characters.

I convert the `data_1` and `data_2` into two dimensional numpy array as follows before giving it to the Embedding layer.

```
data_1=np.argmax(data_1, axis=2)
data_2=np.argmax(data_2, axis=2)
```

That makes the shape of the data as follows.

```
print(np.shape(data_1)) 
(1434, 185)

print(np.shape(data_2)) 
(283, 185)
```

Each number in the matrix represents index integer.

The multitask model is as under.

```
user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=((185, )), name='Input_1')
products_input =  keras.layers.Input(shape=((185, )), name='Input_2')

shared_embed=(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=185))

user_vec_1 = shared_embed(user_input )
user_vec_2 = shared_embed(products_input )


input_vecs = keras.layers.concatenate([user_vec_1, user_vec_2], name='concat')

input_vecs_1=keras.layers.Flatten()(input_vecs)
input_vecs_2=keras.layers.Flatten()(input_vecs)

# Task 1 FC layers
nn = keras.layers.Dense(90, activation='relu',name='layer_1')(input_vecs_1)
result_a = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_1')(nn)



# Task 2 FC layers
nn1 = keras.layers.Dense(90, activation='relu', name='layer_2')(input_vecs_2)
result_b = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear',name='output_2')(nn1) 

model = Model(inputs=[user_input , products_input], outputs=[result_a, result_b])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model is visualized as follows.
[image]

Then I fit the model as follows.

```
model.fit([data_1, data_2], [Y_1,Y_2], epochs=10)
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(1434, 185), (283, 185)]
```

Is there any way in Keras where I can use two different sample size inputs or to some trick to avoid this error to achieve my goal of multitasking regression.

**Here is the minimum working code for testing**.

```
data_1=np.array([[25,  5, 11, 24,  6],
       [25,  5, 11, 24,  6],
       [25,  0, 11, 24,  6],
       [25, 11, 28, 11, 24],
       [25, 11,  6, 11, 11]])

data_2=np.array([[25, 11, 31,  6, 11],
       [25, 11, 28, 11, 31],
       [25, 11, 11, 11, 31]])

Y_1=np.array([[2.33],
       [2.59],
       [2.59],
       [2.54],
       [4.06]])


Y_2=np.array([[2.9],
       [2.54],
       [4.06]])



user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=((5, )), name='Input_1')
products_input =  keras.layers.Input(shape=((5, )), name='Input_2')

shared_embed=(keras.layers.Embedding(37, 3, input_length=5))
user_vec_1 = shared_embed(user_input )
user_vec_2 = shared_embed(products_input )

input_vecs = keras.layers.concatenate([user_vec_1, user_vec_2], name='concat')


input_vecs_1=keras.layers.Flatten()(input_vecs) 
input_vecs_2=keras.layers.Flatten()(input_vecs)

    nn = keras.layers.Dense(90, activation='relu',name='layer_1')(input_vecs_1)
    result_a = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_1')(nn)

    # Task 2 FC layers
    nn1 = keras.layers.Dense(90, activation='relu', name='layer_2')(input_vecs_2)

    result_b = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear',name='output_2')(nn1)

model = Model(inputs=[user_input , products_input], outputs=[result_a, result_b])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([data_1, data_2], [Y_1,Y_2], epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**:

Here I am writing a solution with TensorFlow 2.
So, what you need is:

1. to define a dynamic input that takes its shape from the data
2. to use average pooling so your dens layer dimension is independent of input dimensions.
3. to calculate losses separately

Here is your example modified to work:

```
## Do this
#pip install tensorflow==2.0.0

import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


data_1=np.array([[25,  5, 11, 24,  6],
       [25,  5, 11, 24,  6],
       [25,  0, 11, 24,  6],
       [25, 11, 28, 11, 24],
       [25, 11,  6, 11, 11]])

data_2=np.array([[25, 11, 31,  6, 11],
       [25, 11, 28, 11, 31],
       [25, 11, 11, 11, 31]])

Y_1=np.array([[2.33],
       [2.59],
       [2.59],
       [2.54],
       [4.06]])


Y_2=np.array([[2.9],
       [2.54],
       [4.06]])



user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=((None,)), name='Input_1')
products_input =  keras.layers.Input(shape=((None,)), name='Input_2')

shared_embed=(keras.layers.Embedding(37, 3, input_length=5))
user_vec_1 = shared_embed(user_input )
user_vec_2 = shared_embed(products_input )

x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(user_vec_1)
nn = keras.layers.Dense(90, activation='relu',name='layer_1')(x)
result_a = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_1')(nn)

# Task 2 FC layers
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(user_vec_2)
nn1 = keras.layers.Dense(90, activation='relu', name='layer_2')(x)

result_b = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear',name='output_2')(nn1)

model = Model(inputs=[user_input , products_input], outputs=[result_a, result_b])


loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

loss_values = []
num_iter = 300
for i in range(num_iter):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Forward pass.
        logits = model([data_1, data_2])          
        loss_value = loss(Y_1, logits[0]) + loss(Y_2, logits[1]) 
        loss_values.append(loss_value)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)          
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(num_iter), loss_values)
plt.xlabel("iterations")
plt.ylabel('loss value')
```

[image]

**OLD ANSWER**:

It seems your problem is not a coding problem, it's a machine learning problem! You have to pair your datasets: It means, you have to feed your Keras model on both of its input layers at each round.

The solution is up-sampling your smaller dataset in a way that size of both datasets are same. And the way that you do it depends on the semantics of your datasets. The other option is downsampling your bigger dataset, which is not recommended.

In a very basic situation, if we assume samples are i.i.d. across datasets, you can use the following code:

```
random_indices = np.random.choice(data_2.shape[0],
data_1.shape[0], replace=True) 

upsampled_data_2 = data_2[random_indices]
```

So, you get a new version of your smaller dataset, `upsampled_data_2`, that contains some repeated samples, but with the same size to your bigger dataset.

Comment: May i clarify the steps taken after calculating the losses separately? (for loop).. would you proceed downstream to use model.predict etc?or does the model then have to be fit but with some of the factors calculated in the for loop? thank you

Comment: @user9317212, if you want to know how things work here, read this tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UCJt8EYjlzCs1H1d1X0iDGYJsHKwu-NO

Comment: Thank you I will! I am looking for a similar work around with a simple sequential model with two sets of data that have different sample sizes but would like to merge one common layer... I still need to be able to see model performance , stop at certain epochs etc..

Comment: could you please let me know how to evaluate the model (how to use the model to predict unseen data) for example `data_2_train =np.array([[22, 44, 1,  6, 5],
       [4, 1, 2, 11, 31],
       [25, 6, 11, 11, 31]])

ev = model.predic(data_2_train)`

Comment: @javac just use `model.predict`. It's a Keras model so evaluation is the same as usual.

Comment: @moh Thank you, this is how I use the ` model.predict` to predict   `ev1 = model.predict([data_1,data_1])`  both arrays are data_1 and we have to pass two arrays and this is the output  `[array([[2.6645594],
       [2.6645594],
       [2.725228 ],
       [2.7914689],
       [3.3037999]], dtype=float32), array([[2.6815317],
       [2.6815317],
       [2.7365377],
       [2.7890966],
       [3.276105 ]], dtype=float32)]`    is this right ?

Comment: @moh, my second question is I am using LSTM and do not have an embedding layer so how to feed the input layer to GlobalAveragePooling1D?

Comment: @javac Your output seems right. For LSTM you should think about a trick, depends on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear in your question if you're trying to:

1. Build a single model that takes a `user` and a `product`, and predicts two things about that `(user, product)` pair.  If the `user` and `product` aren't paired, then it's not clear that this means anything (as @matias-valdenegro pointed out). If you pair up a random element of the other type (as in [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253880/997378)).. hopefully each output will just learn to ignore the other input. This would be equivalent to:
2. Build two models, that share an embedding layer (in which case the concat doesn't make any sense). If `Y1` has the same length as `data1` and `Y2` has the same shape as `data2` then this is probably what you want. This way if you have a `user` you can run the `user` model, and if you have a `product` you can run the `product` model.

I think you really want #2. To train it you can do something like:

```
for user_batch, product_batch in zip(user_data.shuffle().repeat(), 
                                     product_data.shuffle().repeat()): 
  user_model.train_on_batch(*user_batch)
  product_model.train_on_batch(*product_batch)
  step = 1
  if step > STEPS:
    break
```

Or, wrap them both in a combined model:

```
user_result = user_model(user_input)
product_result = product_model(product_input)

model = Model(inputs=[user_input , products_input], 
              outputs=[user_result, product_result])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([data_1, data_2], [Y_1,Y_2], epochs=10)
```

Regardless of which training procedure you use, you should normalized the output ranges so that the two model's losses are comparable. The first procedure will alternate epochs or steps. The second does a single gradient step on the weighted sum of the two losses. You may want to check which loss weighting works best for you.

Comment: @mdsoust regarding the `keras.layers.concatenate`, please refer to the (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197895/what-does-concatenate-layers-do-in-keras-multitask) which mentions the use of `keras.layers.concatenate` for multitasking.

Comment: Do I need to compile both the models separately?

Comment: Compile both the models separately? If you use the alternating training: Yes.

Comment: `keras.layers.concatenate` for multitasking. Yes, it makes sense if all the output heads need to depend on all the inputs. But I don't think that is your case. it doesn't make sense for unpaired data. Please clarify.

Comment: In my case, all the output heads should be predicted while considering all the inputs

Comment: > all the output heads should be predicted while considering all the inputs

Thanks for clarifying. 

So the last thing you need to clarify then is: Why are your two input datasets different shapes?

Comment: Because they are two different data sets but are highly related to each other. That is why, multitasking might help.

Comment: @AbdulKarimKhan did you find a solution for multitasking with different samples?

Comment: @mdaoust could you please write what is the user_model and product_model  because if we use the above then we face --> `ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(5, 5), (3, 5)]`

Answer (score 1):

For this answer, I will suppose you "don't have any rule for pairing users and products", and that you simply want to sample randomly.

Although there is already an answer for this, that answer is biased because it will have fixed pairs and you will want to vary pairs. For this you will want to have a generator:

```
def generator(data_1, data_2, y1, y2, batchSize):

    l1 = len(data_1)
    l2 = len(data_2)

    #extending data 2 to the same size of data 1
    sampleRelation = l1 // l2 #l1 must be bigger
    if l1 % l2 > 0:
        sampleRelation += 1

    data_2 = np.concatenate([data_2] * sampleRelation, axis=0)
    y2 = np.concatenate([y2] * sampleRelation, axis=0)
    data_2 = data_2[:l1]
    y2 = y2[:l1]


    #batches per epoch = steps_per_epoch
    batches = l1 // batchSize
    if l1 % batchSize > 0:
       batches += 1

    while True:  #keras generators must be infinite

        #shuffle indices in every epoch
        np.random.shuffle(data_1)
        np.random.shuffle(data_2)

        #batch loop
        for b in range(batches):
            start = b*batchSize
            end = start + batchSize

            yield [data_1[start:end], data_2[start:end]], [y1[start:end], y2[start:end]]
```

Train your model with `model.fit_generator(generator(data_1, data_2, Y_1, Y_2, batchSize), steps_per_epoch = same_number_of_batches_as_inside_generator, ...)`

---

If my guess is correct, you don't want any relation between user and product, and simply want to train two models simultaneously. In this case, I suggest this architecture:

[image: Architecture picture]